# python/pandas: why the empty dataframe when using isin?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to find where "code" from df2 appears in any of the "code1,code2,code3" columns in df1 and return the rows from df2 where that match was successful.

Here is my sample code:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
        {
        'terms' : ['term1','term2'],
        'code1': ['1234x', '4321y'],
        'code2': ['2345x','5432y'],
        'code3': ['3456x','6543y']
        }
        )
df1 = df1[['terms'] + df1.columns[:-1].tolist()]

df2 = pd.DataFrame(
        {
        'name': ['Dan','Sara'],
        'rate': ['3','3.5'],
        'location': ['FL','OH'],
        'code': ['4444g','6543y']                           
         })
df2 = df2[['name','rate','location','code']]

#combining code1,code2,code3 into new column df1['allcodes']
df1['allcodes'] = df1[df1.columns[1:]].apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.dropna().astype(str)),axis=1)

print(df2[df2['code'].isin(df1['allcodes'])])
```

The desired result would be the row from df2 where the code was found in df1:

```
   name rate location   code
1  Sara  3.5       OH  6543y
```

The result is:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [name, rate, location, code]
Index: []
```

why is this returning an empty dataframe?

Comment: Is it your intention to test each code in `df2.code` and determine if it is in any of the rows of `df1`?  Or does the check have to be limited to just the corresponding row from `df1`?

Comment: I want to see if the code for each row in df2 is present in df1. If the df2 code is present, I want to return that row in df2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1**
`np.in1d`
Indiscriminate check if a `df2.code` for a particular row is anywhere in `df1`

```
df2[np.in1d(df2.code, df1[['code1', 'code2', 'code3']])]

   name rate location   code
1  Sara  3.5       OH  6543y
```

Speed it up

```
df2[np.in1d(df2.code.values, df1[['code1', 'code2', 'code3']].values)]
```

---

**Option 2**
Check to see if `df2.loc[x, 'code']` is in `df1.loc[x]`
We use the `pd.DataFrame.eq` method so we can pass the `axis=0` parameter which checks if a series is equal to each column.  Basically, `axis=0` means, align the index (not columns).

```
df2[df1[['code1', 'code2', 'code3']].eq(df2.code, 0).any(1)]

   name rate location   code
1  Sara  3.5       OH  6543y
```

Speed it up

```
df2[(df1[['code1', 'code2', 'code3']].values == df2['code'].values[:, None]).any(1)]
```

Comment: This is amazing!

Comment: Thank you @Vaishali

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Why does adding ".values" speed up the results?

Comment: @mattrweaver Sometimes our operations work on arrays and don't need the overhead of tracking an index. This is one of those times. The values attribute points to the underlying numpy array.

Answer (score 2):

Use, `filter` and `stack`

```
In [4647]: df2[df2['code'].isin(df1.filter(like='code').stack())]
Out[4647]:
   name rate location   code
1  Sara  3.5       OH  6543y
```

Or, if you're use about `code*` columns to be after `1:`

```
In [4648]: df2[df2['code'].isin(df1[df1.columns[1:]].stack())]
Out[4648]:
   name rate location   code
1  Sara  3.5       OH  6543y
```

---

Details

```
In [4649]: df1.filter(like='code')
Out[4649]:
   code1  code2  code3
0  1234x  2345x  3456x
1  4321y  5432y  6543y

In [4650]: df1.filter(like='code').stack()
Out[4650]:
0  code1    1234x
   code2    2345x
   code3    3456x
1  code1    4321y
   code2    5432y
   code3    6543y
dtype: object

In [4651]: df2['code'].isin(df1.filter(like='code').stack())
Out[4651]:
0    False
1     True
Name: code, dtype: bool
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the detailed explanation. Between both answers, it is clear there are many ways to accomplish what I need.